# Discord.js 14.9 - Editing a Message - Error

Tags: discord.js

I am Attempting to edit a previous ephemeral reply using Discord.js V14.9.

The issue I am Facing is when attempting to edit the origional message (from a button interaction) using
interaction.message.edit()
I get a DiscordAPI Error[10008]: Unknown Message.

Wven though when I console.debug(interaction.message)
I get back the message object
also when debugging interaction.message.editable true is returned.

Here is a snipped of my code :

`if(interaction.isButton()){ const messaage =  interaction.message; message.edit({Options}); }`

It may be worth Noting this comes through a string of interactions Button -> Modal -> Button (Here being where I want to edit the origional reply to the Modal interaction)

any help would be much appreciated as scanning through the docs and repo/debugging hasnt turned anything up

Answer (score -1):

instead of this:

```
interaction.edit({options})
```

use this:

```
interaction.update({options})
```